# Connecting my phone on my pc via usb only show the driver folder

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, usb

I want to add files to my SD card but when I connect my phone via USB to my computer, it will add those 3 (E: F: and G:):

[image]

On E: i got:

[image]

And when I try to access F: And G:, it says that I need to insert a disk in it.

I tried the following change:
-Activate USB debug
-Change to use USB for charge only then to MTP again

So how can i access the files on my SD card?

More information:
Phone: Alcatel Idol 3
Android version: 6.0.1
Windows 7 & 8
A 8gb SD card is inserted in my phone

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried installation of the USB drivers for your device first, then plug in the phone to your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found by @RMarkwald in the comments

I copied the file from the Driver folder and executed the install64.exe . I repluged my phone and I have now access to the sd card.

Comment: Glad to hear you are working!